# Better alternative to try method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I would like a clean piece of code and I think this feels clunky.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
User.try(:profile).try(:settings).try(:card).try(:options)
```

If I eliminate the try methods, I get a nil method error.

Is there another piece of code that does something like:

```
User.try(:profile,:settings, :card, :options)
```

Comment: BTW the reason why `User.try(:profile,:settings, :card, :options)` doesn't work is due to the fact that you can provide method parameters and blocks with try. The above code tries to do `User.profile(:settings, :card, :options)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ruby 2.3.0 you can use `&.` method instead of `try`:

```
User&.profile&.settings&.card&.options
```

But you should avoid things like this.

When you send messages to objects that might return `nil` or when the object doesn't respond to that message, that's a problem you should solve on its own. Using `try` only exacerbates the problem, in the same way that `nil`-checking does. **Write consistent interfaces that behave consistently.**

Comment: If `User` is an uninitialized constant, it raises a NameError error, so, the safe navigation operator won't work as expected.

Comment: @SebastianPalma it will raise an error about uninitialized constant before method `profile` will be tried.

Comment: As an aside `try` and safe navigation `&.` are not exactly equivalent [Spec](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/AStry-vs-and-Safe-Navigation)

Comment: ^ `a&.b` = `a.nil? ? nil : a.b` whereas `a.try(:b)` = `a.respond_to?(:b) ? a.b : nil`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Ruby version greater than 2.3, you can use the safe operator instead. For example,

```
User.profile&.settings&.card&.options
```

Isn't that neat?

Answer (score 3):

**Just for fun**

Roll your own:

```
# concerns/deep_try.rb

module DeepTry
  def deep_try(*methods)
    methods.reduce(self) { |receiver, method| receiver.try(method) }
  end
end

# user.rb (or anywhere else you want it)
extend DeepTry
```

That would let you safely call the following:

```
User.deep_try(:profile, :settings, :card, :options)
```

You could also use on an instance level:

```
@user.extend(DeepTry).deep_try(:profile, :settings, :card, :options)
```

Comment: tbh, I'd leave out the `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` and `class_methods do`. You can use `extend` inside a class (instead of `include`) to do the same thing. This also allow you to apply it over instances, without adding it to the class. eg. `User.last.extend(DeepTry).deep_try(:profile, :settings, :card, :options)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @3limin4t0r - great steer. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is out in left field, but you know, diversity in thinking.

I have created the (very tiny) insouciant gem that allows code to be executed with worrying about errors. Using this gem the code would look like:

```
insouciant(nil) { User.profile.settings.card.options }
```

with the slight added "benefit" of catching all standard errors, not just nil method errors. The nil value is returned on an error. You can replaced it with some other value if that makes more sense in your application.

Omitting the parameter entirely will return the error message as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the other answers.

In the case that you have something like:

```
user.try{|u| "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}"}
```

You can use the `&.` operator in conjunction with the `then` method:

```
user&.then{|u| "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}"}
```